# Some error occures after send request to the function url

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot, telegraf

I set up a one firebase function to send messages to my bot. But when firebase gets request I can see that some error occurred.

```
FetchError: request to https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT-TOKEN>/getMe failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.telegram.org:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1453:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

and

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:595:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (/worker/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:357:8)
    at /srv/index.js:30:13
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

But secound one I suppose does not influence on the result.

As a result, I don't get any message to my to Bot.

The next script that i use:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const telegraf = require('telegraf');
const axios = require('axios');

const bot = new telegraf('<BOT-TOKEN>')
bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome!'))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply('Send me a sticker'))
bot.on('sticker', (ctx) => ctx.reply(''))
bot.hears('hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hey there'))
bot.launch()

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, res) => {
    const token = '<BOT-TOKEN>';
    const url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage`;
    axios.post(url, {
        chat_id: '154866113',
        text: "just do it!"
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        res.send({ status: "O"});
        return 'ok';
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      });
    res.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Comment: I don’t know anything about telegram bots but it seems strange that you call some methods (e.g. bot.start()) outside the Cloud Function itself. When are these methods going to be executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN error means that you need to switch to the "Flame" or "Blaze" pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

The telegram API is not a Google-owned service, so you need to switch to the "Flame" or "Blaze" plan.

Comment: Yes, I missed one, you are right. That a fail reason. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any other service Firebase-like to use to host Telegram Bots?

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing happened with me. I switched to a different wifi from Bsnl to mobile hotspot of Jio to be specific.
Following was my error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the answer to the `EAI_AGAIN` error is due to a malformed URI. Are you sure `https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT-TOKEN>/getMe` is the correct URI and is accessible from where ever this script is being run from?

The second error is due to you calling the `res.send()` method more than once. Express `res` objects wrap Node's [`ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object, and once the connection is closed via `write` or `end`, it cannot be sent again. Try removing the `res.send("Hello from Firebase!");` section of your code and coming back.